# What can we conclude from isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, logic

Suppose we have some **linear group** $\mathcal{G}_n(R)$ over *pretty good* (commutative, has identity) infinite ring $R$. $\mathcal{G}_n$ can be one of ${\rm GL}_n, {\rm PGL}_n {\rm SL}_n, {\rm PSL}_n, {\rm Sp}_n, {\rm PSp}_n$ and of course it is fixed. And suppose that there is another group $G$ which is **isomorphic** to our group $\mathcal{G}_n$. What can we say about $G$?

1. Can we say that $G$ also have to be linear?
2. If 1 is true, can we say that $G$ has the same dimensionality as $\mathcal{G}_n(R)$?
3. If 1 and 2 are true, can we say something about rings?

In fact, this question arises when I'm trying to analyse **elementary equivalence** of linear group over some field $\mathcal{G}_n(\mathbb{K})$ and some other group $G$. From *Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem* we can analyse $\mathcal{G}_n(R)$ and its **isomorphism** to $G'$, where $R$ is some ultra-power of $\mathbb{K}$ and $G'$ is an ultra-power of $G$.

If my questions are not true for ${\rm GL}_n$ then it is not vital since this group is differ from others in some sence.

Comment: If you do not assume anything about the group $G$, it would be hard. For instance take $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ we know that there is a bijection $\psi$ of this set onto $\mathbb{R}$. Then $G:=(\mathbb{R},._{\psi})$ with $x._{\psi}y:=\psi(\psi^{-1}(x)\psi^{-1}(y))$ is a group and $\psi$ is (by definition) an isomorphism. However the group $G$ does not carry any interesting structure.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin yep, we can do this trick in each case. I will try to formulate my thoughts more precise. Since in your example it is just the same group but with awkward multiplication.

Comment: First, how do you define a group to be linear in this context?